# How to get innerHTML of each element in a node list

Tags: dom, nodelist, reason, bucklescript, bs-webapi

Say I have the following html:

```
<div class="item">one</div>
<div class="item">two</div>
<div class="item">three</div>
```

I would like to log the innerHTML for each element. I have tried the following:

```
document
|> Document.querySelectorAll(".item")
|> NodeList.toArray /* not sure if this is needed */
|> Array.map(Document.ofNode) /* not sure if this is needed */
|> Array.map(Element.innerHTML)
|> Array.iter((number) => {
  Js.log(number);
});
```

The error is on line `|> Array.map(Element.innerHTML)`

And the error is:

```
This has type:
    array(Webapi.Dom.Element.t) => array(string)
  But somewhere wanted:
    array(Dom.node) => 'a
```

How can I use the `Dom.node` so that I access the `innerHTML`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Document.ofNode` should be `Element.ofNode`, but the error message indicates that this line isn't present at all in the code producing the error. `ofNode` also returns an `option`, since not all nodes are elements, so you have to unwrap that as well. Something like this should work:

```rust
document
|> Document.querySelectorAll(".item")
|> NodeList.toArray
|> Array.map(Element.ofNode)
|> Array.map(Js.Option.getExn)
|> Array.map(Element.innerHTML)
|> Array.iter(Js.log);
```

Or to avoid a bit of unnecessary array allocation and mapping:

```rust
document
|> Document.querySelectorAll(".item")
|> NodeList.toArray
|> Array.iter(node =>
   node
   |> Element.ofNode
   |> Js.Option.getExn
   |> Element.innerHTML
   |> Js.log
  );
```

It also has to be said that direct DOM manipulation isn't a great fit for Reason, or any statically typed functional language for that matter, since the DOM is inherently a very dynamically typed and object-oriented API. `NodeList.toArray`, for example, is required because a `NodeList` is not an array but an "array-like", which supports only a few array operations.